# AWS Security Group settings for public application

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm a bit confused by AWS security groups. I have an application on EC2 that I need accessible to everyone (in theory) in the world. AWS says this though:

"If you use 0.0.0.0/0, you enable all IP addresses to access your instance using SSH or RDP. This is acceptable for the short exercise, but it's unsafe for production environments. In production, you'll authorize only a specific IP address or range of addresses to access your instance."

So, what should I be using for an EC2 instance that I want people to access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If you use 0.0.0.0/0, you enable all IP addresses to access your
>   instance using SSH or RDP.

That statement is in regards to RDP or SSH (your server control mechanism), which you should absolutely have limited to only trusted addresses where you'll be connecting from.

> So, what should I be using for an EC2 instance that I want people to
>   access?

With regards to your application, if you have a large number of people from around the world accessing it, and you don't want to maintain an IP whitelist, then you have no option but to make it available to everyone.

If the service you're providing to people requires them to be able to SSH or RDP to your server, then you'll need to decide if you're willing to put the work into hardening the server and just open up access to everyone or if you want to implement some sort of VPN people need to connect to before gaining access.